# Error while executing node command with php exec function

Tags: php, node.js, apache, centos

I'm trying to execute a nodejs file from php on a Centos server. When the command is executed from the terminal it works fine (also after switching to apache user with the following command su -s /bin/bash apache), but when the code is executed while browsing the file it throws the following exception:

**["","","#","# Fatal error in , line 0","# Check failed: SetPermissions(protect_start, protect_size, PageAllocator::kReadExecute).","#","#","#","#FailureMessage Object: 0x7fffd9b37760"]**

- I have changed also to absolute path, but no luck.
- Gave 777 permission to index.js file.
- Testet from terminal and works fine:

*php -r 'echo exec("/usr/bin/node /var/www/html/index.js /var/www/html/source_files/ 2>&1");'*

```php
 <?php
 try {
       exec("/usr/bin/node /var/www/html/index.js /var/www/html/source_files/ 2>&1", $out, $err);

        if ($err == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {           
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e);
        return 0;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using selinux, try disabling it temporary:

```
setenforce 0
```

Try to run your node.js script. If it run, you probably need to **change selinux httpd settings**. Do following command to list all selinux settings for httpd service:

```
/usr/sbin/getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

You will see two relevant settings `httpd_ssi_exec` and `httpd_execmem`.
Set them on with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_ssi_exec=1
setsebool -P httpd_execmem=1
```

After that try to enable selinux again and run your node.js script to see if the change helped:

```
setenforce 1
```